# Howto handle clash of tasks for two gradle plugins?

Tags: gradle, swagger, build.gradle, artifactory, gradle-plugin

I use gradle with the two plugins `com.jfrog.artifactory` and `io.swagger.core.v3.swagger-gradle-plugin` .

Now I want to configure as described here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/modules/swagger-gradle-plugin the generation of code. But it seems that the `resolve` task has already been defined from artifactory. How do I adress the method of swagger-plugin directly?

This is in my build.gradle:

```
resolve {
   outputFileName = 'bananas'
   outputFileName = 'PetStoreAPI'
   outputFormat = 'JSON'
   prettyPrint = 'TRUE'
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   resourcePackages = ['io.test']
   outputDir = file('test')
}
```

and this is the error message: `Could not set unknown property 'outputFileName' for object of type org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.dsl.ResolverConfig.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is indeed a clash between Artifactory `resolve` extension and Swagger plugin `resolve` tasks (of type `import io.swagger.v3.plugins.gradle.tasks.ResolveTask`)

One way to solve this is to reference the swagger tasks explicitly using fully-qualified name, as follows:

```
io.swagger.v3.plugins.gradle.tasks.ResolveTask swaggerResolve = tasks.getByName("resolve")
swaggerResolve.configure {
    outputFileName = 'PetStoreAPI'
    outputFormat = 'JSON'
    prettyPrint = 'TRUE'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    resourcePackages = ['io.test']
    outputDir = file('test')
}
```

**EDIT**
Simpler solution , see Lukas's comment

```
tasks.resolve { 
   outputFileName = 'PetStoreAPI'
   // ....
}
```

Comment: The (kinda ugly) import is not necessary. You can just use `tasks.resolve { }` to configure the task and `resolve { }` to configure the extension.

Comment: @LukasKörfer you're right, with Groovy DSL you can use this "shorcut" . With Kotlin DSL you would still need to reference ResolveTask using its fully-qualified name (or let me know if  we can avoid this, I'm interested ;) ).  I'll update my answer with your comment, tks.