# Generate OpenAPI YAML File from Swagger Annotations

Tags: gradle, swagger, openapi

I have a java class with the openapi documented using swagger annotations as below. I want to generate the JSON file for this documentation using gradle, but I am unable to do so. I have tried using the `OpenAPI Generator Gradle Plugin` but I believe this plugin works the other way around. How can I generate the JSON file from the swagger annotations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate swagger.json using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39616160/113116)